# Android how to use Viewpager with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, ontouch

i am a coding beginner, so sorry for my bad explanation of the problem.

In my MainActivity I have a full screen Viewpager, which changes its content (the xml-file) every time I swipe left or right. These collection of views is defined in a enum, I have also used a CustomPagerAdapter for that. 
This works fine, but when I implement an onTouchListener in my MainActivity, the "swiping" doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know, how to solve that?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Main = (View) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.colorgroup);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
    View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            viewPager.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            viewPager.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = viewPager.getDrawingCache();
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            String hexColor = String.format( "#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b );
            return true;
        }
    };
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
}
```

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(customPagerEnum.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
    collection.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return CustomPagerEnum.values().length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
    return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
}
```

}

public enum CustomPagerEnum {

```
YELLOW(R.string.YELLOW, R.layout.view_yellow),
PUCE(R.string.PUCE, R.layout.view_puce),
BROWN(R.string.BROWN, R.layout.view_brown),
GREEN(R.string.GREEN, R.layout.view_green),
CYAN(R.string.CYAN, R.layout.view_cyan),
BLUE(R.string.BLUE, R.layout.view_blue),
RED(R.string.RED, R.layout.view_red),
PINK(R.string.PINK, R.layout.view_pink),
PURPLE(R.string.PURPLE, R.layout.view_purple),
SLATE(R.string.SLATE, R.layout.view_slate),
GREY(R.string.GREY, R.layout.view_grey),
DARK(R.string.DARK, R.layout.view_dark);



    private int mTitleResId;
    private int mLayoutResId;

    CustomPagerEnum(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }
```

}

Comment: Don't use enums they require too much overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always return `true` from the `onTouch()` method. This signifies that your handler has consumed the touch event and so the event is not further processed. This results in the swipe never working. Return `false` instead.